# Elasticsearch 7.4 unable to update doc with the same query

Tags: elasticsearch

When I run this in Elasticsearch version 7.13.2 in one server, it works as expected:

```
POST user/_update/AEBFECC4FECC4
{
  "doc": {
   "name": "updated name"
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
 "_index": "user",
 "_type": "_doc",
 "_id": "AEBFECC4FECC4",
 "_version": 9,
 "result": "updated",
 "_shards": {
  "total": 2,
  "successful": 1,
  "failed": 0
 },
 "_seq_no": 89,
 "_primary_term": 1
}
```

However when I do the same query with equivalent index in a different server with version 7.4.1, it returns this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
                "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: script or doc is missing;"
            }
        ],
        "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
        "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: script or doc is missing;"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

What did I miss? Is there a hidden setting somewhere that prevents updating? I read the docs but the update method for version 7.4 is the same as 7.13.

Comment: Can you please check document is available with AEBFECC4FECC4 this id in 7.4 version.

Comment: es raises "document_missing_exception" if the document is not available in the index @SagarPatel